# Is there a way to transport RectTransform into camera ViewPort in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, viewport, rect

Is there a way to transport RectTransform into camera ViewPort  in unity3d ?

I used to try do it several times but it has no result.
I want to make viewport of camera exactly in bounds of proper recttransform.

There is my code:

```
    public static Rect RectTransformToCameraViewport(RectTransform rectTransform)
{
    float leftDownCornerX = (rectTransform.anchoredPosition.x - rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2);
    float leftDownCornerY = (rectTransform.anchoredPosition.y - rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2);

    Vector3 leftCorner = new Vector3(leftDownCornerX, leftDownCornerY, 0);
    Vector3 viewPortLeftCorner = new Vector3(leftCorner.x / Screen.width, leftCorner.y / Screen.height, 0);

    float viewportWidth = Mathf.Abs(rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / Screen.width);
    float viewportHeight = Mathf.Abs(rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / Screen.height);

    return new Rect(0.5f + viewPortLeftCorner.x, 0.5f + viewPortLeftCorner.y, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
}
```

But as I said before it does not work.

## Edit 1:

It works, but it is not work on two diff machines where I work. Maybe there is something with one of those rects.

Maybe you already solved this problem ?

Comment: which camera type are you using? is it Ortho  or Perspective?

Comment: I use perspective camera

Comment: it is incredibly hard to do this.

Comment: @JoeBlow But I did it. Try to use code, that I wrote here. Is it not works ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in one if my previous projects where the camera needed to move to world space UI canvases. Here is my implementation:

```
private static void CalculateCameraTransform(Canvas canvas, float fov, out Vector3 pos, out Quaternion rot)
    {
        var rectTransform = canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        var corners = new Vector3[4]; rectTransform.GetWorldCorners(corners);
        var normal = GetNormalPlane(corners[0], corners[1], corners[2]);
        var distance = Mathf.Cos(fov * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * Vector3.Distance(corners[0], corners[2]) * 0.5f;

        pos = canvas.transform.position + normal * distance;
        rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(-normal);
    }

    private static Vector3 GetNormalPlane(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c) 
    {
        var dir = Vector3.Cross(b - a, c - a);
        var norm = Vector3.Normalize(dir);
        return norm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tend to think that I become not understandable...

My question about VIEWPORT of camera. Viewport that can corresponds recttransform.

Comment: Apologies. Perhaps you could check out RectTransformUtilities class.